# How to confirm that 7zip line command matches output from GUI

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I use the 7zip GUI very often and I am trying to automate some backup archive generation.

Here is the configuration that I can read on the GUI:

```
Archive Format : 7z
Compression Level : Ultra
Compression method: LZMA2
Dictionary Size: 64MB
Word size: 64
Solid Block Size: 4GB
Number of CPU THreads: 8
Update mode: add and replace files (a command)
Pathmode: relative pathnames
Encryption Method: AES-256
```

Of course, the encryption is for the password.

After reading the documentation, I am confused with the use of LZMA2, and I ended up writing the following command:

```
"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" a -t7z C:/MyPath/File.7z -m9=LZMA2 -pMyPassword
```

Yet, I am not sure I met all the parameters described in the GUI. I have the feeling that as soon as you select -m9=LZMA2, then the dictionary is preset and everything else as well...

But how to make sure that I get exactly the same output as when I used the GUI?

What about password encryption and solid block size?

Comment: Just a guess.. but do it both ways, open the GUI and use the `info` option to compare them?

Comment: Ok, you're right, this simple test already shows that the files are different. How to correct my command line?

Comment: If I knew THAT, I would have posted an ANSWER ;)  I myself have used the command line and the GUI 1000 times and never worried about it.  I have to wonder what makes the settings you did in the GUI better?  Hopefully some 7z genius will come along and answer for you.